# How to Enable TLS 1.2 in .Net Application

Tags: .net, tls1.2

Our security team updated the TLS Version from TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2. Due to which I had already updated the .net framework version to 4.8 and added security protocol code as mentioned below:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Still I am facing this error now:

> AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security posture of Azure AD. Your TenantID is: 70115954-0ccd-45f0-87bd-03b2a3587569.

I have also disabled the TLS 1.0, 1.1 in register editor and enabled TLS 1.2.

Comment: If I recall correctly setting the protocol the way you show here was all it took for me. Are you sure the line hits before any of the service calls?

Comment: Please don't post the same text multiple times

Comment: This is the only need, even more, you don't need to change your framework, at least it works even with 4.2 Are you sure you are not getting this error from other source?

Comment: What version of Windows and what version of .Net? Exact build numbers please.